# Show that $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_3$ and reducible over $\Bbb Z_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_3$ and reducible over $\Bbb Z_5$.

I can't figure any way to express $x^2 + 1$ as a product of two polynomials in either ring.  Each product I try either ends up with a number being off by $1$ or $2$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: More generally, $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_p$ (where $p$ is prime) if and only if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$, $k\in\mathbb Z$. See [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B11_and_the_first_supplement).

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_5$, $x^2+1= (x-3)(x-2)$ (or equivalently $(x+3)(x+2)$), for instance.

Comment: How about you calculate the roots with the quadratic formula, instead of making some blind guess?

Comment: You can use the set of quadratic residues modulo $\{3,5,...\}$ to determine whether there is a factor; in particular, modulo $5$, the residues are $0,1,4,4,1$, showing that $2,3$ are roots.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  What do you mean?  I don't see how I would use this for $\Bbb Z_3$

Comment: If $f(x)g(x)=x^2+1$, then (up to an invertible constant) $f(x)=x-\alpha_1$ and $g(x)=x-\alpha_2$, where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are the roots of $x^2+1$ in $\Bbb Z_3$. These must be given by $2^{-1}\cdot(-0\pm\beta)$, where $\beta$ is any number such that $\beta^2=0^2-4\cdot 1=-1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the roots. Over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ we have $$0^2 + 1 = 1 \qquad 1^2 + 1 = 2 \qquad 2^2 + 1 = 2$$ Hence $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible. Over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ we have $$2^2 + 1 = 0 \qquad 3^3 + 1 = 0$$ Thus $$x^2 + 1 = (x + 2)(x + 3)$$ is reducible.

Comment: But how would you write $x^2 + 1$ as a product of two polynomials in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ with one of them being a unit?

Comment: $1 \cdot (x^2 + 1)$ or $2 \cdot (x^2 + 1)$.

Comment: Ah, I see I was misunderstanding the definition of an irreducible polynomial.  So reducibility for $\Bbb Z_5$ would imply that just there exists a product combination that is not a unit $\times$ un-reducible expression?

Comment: Roughly speaking, an irreducible polynomial is a non-constant polynomial, which cannot be factored as two non-constant polynomials. A non-irreducible polynomial is said to be reducible.

Comment: How does $2 \cdot (x^2 + 1) = x^2 + 1$ in $\Bbb Z_3$?

Comment: I think that was dumb. $2$ is for sure a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_3$, but the product is wrong. It is not $x^2 + 1$. Sorry.

Comment: Modulo $5$: $x^2+1=x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proof of the simple result described in the comments: $ x^2 + 1 $ is a quadratic, so it is irreducible over a field $ K $ if and only if it has no roots there. Thus, $ x^2 + 1 $ is irreducible in $ \mathbf F_p $ for an odd prime $ p $ if and only if $ -1 $ is not a quadratic residue in $ \mathbf F_p $. Since the group $ \mathbf F_p^{\times} $ is cyclic, this happens if and only if $ |\mathbf F_p^{\times}| = p-1 $ is not a multiple of $ 4 $, that is, iff $ p \equiv 3 \pmod{4} $.

Answer (score 0):

$ x^2\equiv \text{ either } 1,0 \pmod 3 $

So adding $1$, you can't get zero remainder.

But that is not so in case of 5.

$ 2^2 + 1 =0$
 (mod $5$)